# Statistics: Hypothesis Testing

Tags: statistics

Hypothesis Testing

I have 4 groups of data for four different locations i.e. A, B, C and D (close to each other). In each group, there are 3 columns of data (x, y, z) showing the temperature at the location taken by thermometer at a different height i.e. 50, 100, 150 cm above ground at that location.

How would I use Excel to write some hypotheses to investigate what differences there may be between the temperature measurements at the different locations and heights?

I am thinking about descriptive statistics / T-testing.